# iframe id is changing every tab. How can i immobilize it?

Tags: html, css, imacros

anyone with imacros skill, i have problem with imacros script..

when i doing some script with changed Frame, sometime it F=5, F=6, F=9 , F=12 and else..

when i run, it result tag / error.

can you solve this case?

thank you..

**I am doing auto facebook and twitter share code.**

This my imacros code:

```
        URL GOTO=http://gnctrkcll.turkcell.com.tr/#!/haberler/ben-yaptim-paketyle-kend-paketn-kendn-yarat
        URL GOTO=http://gnctrkcll.turkcell.com.tr/#!/haberler/bu-yilbasi-kutlamalari-sudan-ucuz
        TAB T=1
        FRAME F=9
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Like
        WAIT SECONDS=3
        TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Onayla
        TAB T=2
        FRAME F=0
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMİT ATTR=TYPE:submit&&VALUE:Beğen

        WAIT SECONDS=4

        TAB T=1
        FRAME F=9
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Tweet
        TAB T=2
        FRAME F=9
        TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMİT FORM=ID:update-form ATTR=CLASS:button<SP>selected<SP>submit&&TYPE:submit&&VALUE:Tweetle
```

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to convert you code to javascript format for that and perform additional loop for searching current frame. something like this:

```
var check =  "CODE:";
check+=  "FRAME F={{i}}" + "\n"; 
check+=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Tweet" + "\n"; 
for(i=1;i<=15;i++){
iimSet("i",i);
iimPlay(check);}
```

Comment: You are perfect. How can add it in imacros ?

Comment: save the cod as .js file and put it in your \imacros\macros folder, restart the browser and you'll see it in the list of your imacros script - run it by click on Play button

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do a little change of the code and make a function that searches the frame number like this

```
///main code

var frame=SearchFrame();

//use frame to set into macro and play it





function SearchFrame()
{

var check =  "CODE:";
check+=  "FRAME F={{i}}" + "\n"; 
check+=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Tweet CONTENT=EVEN:MOUSEOVER" + "\n"; 

frame=0;

for(i=1;i<=15;i++){
iimSet("i",i)

//if the result of the macro is true save frame number and break
if(iimPlay(check)==true)
{

frame=i;
break;
}
}
//return frame number
return frame;


}
```

Comment: You are perfect. How can add it in imacros ?

Comment: First you have to write the code in .js file NOT .iim file. I will write another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've used your code in first post and placed changing frame next to Tweet button.

```
///////macro declaration////////////

var mainMacro;

mainMacro ="CODE:";

mainMacro +="URL GOTO=http://gnctrkcll.turkcell.com.tr/#!/haberler/ben-yaptim-paketyle-kend-paketn-kendn-yarat"+"\n";
mainMacro +="URL GOTO=http://gnctrkcll.turkcell.com.tr/#!/haberler/bu-yilbasi-kutlamalari-sudan-ucuz"+"\n";
mainMacro +="TAB T=1"+"\n";
mainMacro +="FRAME F=9"+"\n";
mainMacro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Like"+"\n";
mainMacro +="WAIT SECONDS=3"+"\n";
mainMacro +="TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Onayla"+"\n";
mainMacro +="TAB T=2"+"\n";
mainMacro +="FRAME F=0"+"\n";
mainMacro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=TYPE:submit&&VALUE:Begen"+"\n";
mainMacro +="WAIT SECONDS=4"+"\n";

var mainMacro1="CODE:";
mainMacro1 +="TAB T=1"+"\n";
mainMacro1 +="FRAME F={{frame}}"+"\n";
mainMacro1 +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Tweet"+"\n";
mainMacro1 +="TAB T=2"+"\n";
mainMacro1 +="FRAME F=9"+"\n";
mainMacro1 +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:update-form ATTR=CLASS:button<SP>selected<SP>submit&&TYPE:submit&&VALUE:Tweetle"+"\n";


//////////Beginning/////////////

iimPlay(mainMacro)

//calling for the function which will find the frame
var frame=SearchFrame();

iimSet("frame",frame)
iimPlay(mainMacro1)




function SearchFrame()
{

var check =  "CODE:";
check+=  "FRAME F={{i}}" + "\n"; 
check+=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Tweet CONTENT=EVEN:MOUSEOVER" + "\n"; 

frame=0;

for(i=1;i<=15;i++){
iimSet("i",i)

//if the result of the macro is true save frame number and break
if(iimPlay(check)==true)
{

frame=i;
break;
}
}
//return frame number
return frame;


}
```

I hope this works. I had to split your macro into 2 macros. First will navigate to the link and second will hit the Tweet button. If it doesn't work do a little work on your own and it will.

Comment: Thanks you for helps. I have problem i can't adapt it.

Comment: i don't know javascript , i was tried change that code but i can't do it. http://jsfiddle.net/gyDaD/

Comment: it's auto like on facebook but it isn't pass next step auto share on twitter.

Comment: Then use RECORD option and record the proper command for that part of the macro.