# Imacro for changing frame

Tags: macros, browser-automation, imacros

I am trying to record a macro for auto posting on a website but problem is that one text field is changing its frame id every time when the macro tries to post, so it is not possible for me to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it if you run your imacros code from javascript js file  - all you need is loop which will go over all possible frame id's until find current one.
here is example of the code:

```
var find_frame;
find_frame =  "CODE:";
find_frame +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
find_frame +=  "set !timeout_step 2" + "\n";
find_frame +=  "frame f={{i}}" + "\n";
find_frame +=  "code to check if frame is correct" + "\n";   
for (i=1;i<=max_frame_id,i++){
iimSet("i",i);
iimPlay(find_frame);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above can work but the same kind of question is answered here.

[iframe id is changing every tab. How can i immobilize it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033550/iframe-id-is-changing-every-tab-how-can-i-immobilize-it)